# Find out which command is running within a screen session

Tags: gnu-screen

I often leave tasks running within screen so that I can check on them later, but I sometimes need to check which command is running within the screen. It's usually a php script of sorts, such as

```
screen -d -m nice -n -10 php -f convertThread.php start=10000
```

I don't record which screens are running which command, but I'd like to be able to get a feel for the progress made by checking what command was run within it, without killing the process.

I don't see any option for this within the screen help pages.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I recently had to do this. On Stack Overflow I answered how to [find the PID of the process running in screen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28395244/343302). Once you have the PID you can use `ps` to get the command. Here is the contents of that answer with some additional content to address your situation:

You can get the PID of the screen sessions here like so:

```
$ screen -ls
There are screens on:
        1934.foo_Server         (01/25/15 15:26:01)     (Detached)
        1876.foo_Webserver      (01/25/15 15:25:37)     (Detached)
        1814.foo_Monitor        (01/25/15 15:25:13)     (Detached)
3 Sockets in /var/run/screen/S-ubuntu.
```

Let us suppose that you want the PID of the program running in Bash in the `foo_Monitor` screen session. Use the PID of the `foo_Monitor` screen session to get the PID of the `bash` session running in it by searching PPIDs (Parent PID) for the known PID:

```
$ ps -el | grep 1814 | grep bash
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
0 S  1000  1815  1814  0  80   0 -  5520 wait   pts/1    00:00:00 bash
```

Now get just the PID of the `bash` session:

```
$ ps -el | grep 1814 | grep bash | awk '{print $4}'
1815
```

Now we want the process with *that* PID. Just nest the commands, and this time use the `-v` flag on `grep bash` to get the process that is *not* bash:

```
$ echo $(ps -el | grep $(ps -el | grep 1814 | grep bash | awk '{print $4}') | grep -v bash | awk '{print $4}')
23869
```

We can use that PID to find the command (Look at the end of the second line):

```
$ ps u -p 23869
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
dotanco+ 18345 12.1 20.1 5258484 3307860 ?     Sl   Feb02 1147:09 /usr/lib/foo
```

**Put it all together:**

```
$ ps u -p $(ps -el | grep $(ps -el | grep SCREEN_SESSION_PID | grep bash | awk '{print $4}') | grep -v bash | awk '{print $4}')
```

Comment: Oh, clever! I like it! Since this answers the question directly, I'm going to accept this answer. I appreciate it! Sorry @Ghanima (:'

Answer (score 7):

What about using `screen -S <your-fancy-name>` to give the screen sessions meaningful names according to the commands they run? Names will be listed with `screen -ls` and be used to resume a session by `screen -r <your-fancy-name>`.

Edit to add:

Since it has been brought to my attention just the other day. `tmux` offers quite the same set of functionality as `screen` (if not even more) and comes with a feature fitting your needs. From the FAQ: "tmux supports automatically renaming windows to the running application without gross hacks using escape sequences. Its even on by default."