# Get a list of children process ids (PIDs) running in a screen session

Tags: gnu-screen

How can I run a command that lists all PIDs of the processes running under a certain screen (suppose multiple bash processes are running, because I have opened multiple tabs)?. I found the following post: [Find out which command is running within a screen session](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153808/find-out-which-command-is-running-within-a-screen-session/183750#183750?newreg=a6e35355ab77440e978ea60fca3ca933)

That command works when there is only one process running within a screen, but it fails when I have more than one tab open in the screen session. The error I get is as follows:

## command:

```
ps u -p $(ps -el | grep $(ps -el | grep 28572 | grep bash | awk '{print $4}') | grep -v bash | awk '{print $4}')
```

## output:

grep: 28573: No such file or directory

## UPDATE:

The following sequences of commands yield the expected results.

1. Get all screen processes

   ```
   ps waux | grep -i screen | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | paste -s -d,
   ```
2. Get all the processes running under the screen sessions

   ```
   pgrep -P $(ps waux | grep -i screen | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | paste -s -d,) | paste -s -d,
   ```
3. Get all the java processes running under the processes running under the screen sessions

   ```
   ps -w -p $(pgrep -P $(pgrep -P $(ps waux | grep -i screen | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | paste -s -d,) | paste -s -d,) | paste -s -d,) | grep java
   ```

Things to note:

1. I only care about `java` processes running within the screen sessions.
2. I am using the `paste` command to get a comma-separated list of process identifiers, which I then use as the parameter of the `-P` option of the `pgrep` command.

## UPDATE 2:

I found a way of avoiding using the `paste` command by using `xargs`:

```
ps waux | grep -i screen | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I{} pgrep -P {} | xargs -I{} pgrep -P {} | xargs -I{} ps -w -p {} |  grep java
```

Comment: try using the pstree command

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro so if I run the pstree command I get the following: pstree 28572

`screen─┬─bash
       └─bash───java───30*[{java}]` .  How can I get the pid of the java process?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it would only work if there was one screen session open, though.

```
ps waux | grep screen$ | awk '{print $2}' | xargs pstree
```

For example

```
jeff@linux:~$ ps waux | grep screen$ | awk '{print $2}' | xargs pstree
screen───screen─┬─bash───top
                ├─bash───watch
                └─bash───xargs───pstree
```

If you had multiple screen sessions, you could iterate over them like this:

```
jeff@jlinux:~$ for pid in $(ps waux | grep screen$ | awk '{print $2}'); do pstree $pid; done
screen───screen───bash
screen───screen─┬─bash───top
                ├─bash───watch
                └─bash───pstree
```

Comment: Thank you Jeff, but I actually want to get the PIDs of `top`, `watch` and `pstree` in this particular case. I will update the title of my question.

Comment: @MiltonInostrozaAguilera just add the "-p" flag to pstree

Comment: for some reason, the command for multiple screen session come up empty. I verified that I have more than one screen session by running `screen -ls`:  

There are screens on:

 31136.test1 (Detached)

 12989.test2 (Detached)

 28572.test3 (Detached)


However, when I run your command the result is empty.

Comment: sorry for the non formatted text, but I tried formatting and it didn't quite work out :S. Is it possible to just the list of PIDs rather than the grapichal tree?

Comment: I think I got what I was looking for. Updating my initial question.