# Checking if a script is running in the screen remotely

Tags: linux, command, gnu-screen

I want to check whether the script `test.sh` is running or not in the screen(GNU screen) named `testscreen`.
Need to do this job for many servers, so, want to do through ssh remotely.

```
for serverid in {1..100}; do ssh root@server${serverid} "command"
```

How can I make `command` to check the script `test.sh` is running or not in the screen named `testscreen`?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153808/find-out-which-command-is-running-within-a-screen-session

Answer (score 1):

using

```
screen -Q windows
```

you can list the windows including the started commands in each.

So, to inspect a specific session

```
screen -S testscreen -Q windows
```

To test for the presence of a specific command `test.sh`:

```
screen -S testscreen -Q windows | grep -E '^[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+test\.sh$'
```

(note that this is the window title)

running this via `ssh` just works:

```bash
for serverid in {1..100}; do 
  ssh root@server${serverid} screen -S testscreen -Q windows \
    | grep -q -E '^[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+test\.sh$' \
    && echo "command running!" \
    || echo "not running!"
done
```

Comment: Just wondering - why not `grep -q` instead of redirecting stdout to `/dev/null`? Is it not not  a standard flag?

Comment: @aviro honestly, for me it's just "muscle memory"; you're right `-q` would be more elegant. I don't think it's non-standard (and that wouldn't matter much – on a machine with GNU screen, having GNU coreutils feels rather likely).